# Term that describes one who is an expert in a subject without having any first-hand experience?

Tags: single-word-requests

I learned about this in college, but have since forgotten over the decades. An example is an anthropologist who has learned about a tribe but has never actually visited and studied the tribe first hand.

Comment: Are you simply asking for the term for who one who **falsely** believes oneself to be an expert? The reference to 'first-hand experience' confuses the matter, because in highly theoretical fields it may not be obvious what would constitute first-hand experience.

Comment: Probly _self-confidence_. At least, that's what many people believe it means.

Comment: Such a person would be called _book smart_, but I'm not sure that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @jsw I don't think the term implies any sort of Dunning-Kruger effect, it just differentiates a person who doesn't have experience in the topic they have learned.  Basically, it is a technical term similar to armchair expert per my comment to Nuclear Wang

Comment: O.K., so you are looking for a term for somebody who **does** have some relevant knowledge, but the knowledge is all of the kind that is acquired in a classroom or a library, rather than in the field. That probably needs to be more explicitly stated in the question, to make it clear that it is not a duplicate of the listed ones. Mr. Lister's *book smart* seems to capture the concept, but it looks like you are looking for something more formal.

Comment: Yeah, I edited the question.  For all I know, the word doesn't exist and I have a false memory of this class from a couple of decades ago, but I figured it couldn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 3):

This person could be described as an ***armchair expert***, or an ***armchair X***, where ***X*** is  some occupation (e.g. armchair detective, armchair anthropologist). They may be well-versed  in a topic, having studied many books from the comfort of their armchair, but they have little to no practical experience in the field they're studying. They might sound knowledgeable about a subject, but it's entirely possible that their knowledge has little to no bearing on the real world, as it is entirely untested in a practical application.

Comment: It basically means the same thing as armchair expert, but the word itself was technical/academic and not a colloquialism.

Answer (score 1):

You're possibly thinking of the [Dunning-Kruger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) by which people who lack competence in some area are thus unable to judge their own level of competence and often over-estimate it.

As far as I know, there is no single word for this.